# How to call a method inside getDerivedStateFromProps in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getderivedstatefromprops

I have a method inside my React class e.g. `someMethod()`. I also have a `getDerivedStateFromProps()` method in which I want to call `someMethod()`. Yes I need to do this in `getDerivedStateFromProps` and not in `componentDidUpdate()` for example because I do change the state in `someMethod()`.

```
someMethod() {
    this.setState({worked: true});
    return 'worked';
}

static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    console.log(someMethod());
}
```

I would like for the log of `worked` to be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getDerivedStateFromProps` you don't have an access to the component's instance. So, basically, you can't. But what you can do is return an object to update the state.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return { worked: true }
}
```

Comment: What if the method I want to call is triggered by an onClick event. I can't just tell react to update...

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how the onClick event is connected with `getDerivedStateFromProps`. Do you mind sharing the code or giving some more detailed explanation of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You know what it took me a 300-word comment, I was just about to post it, explaining exactly why I need to call a method in `getDerivedStateFromProps` when it hit me, IT DOESN'T. XD ^_^. I figured it out so thanks :DD